# Is there any reason to do a solution using a dynamically created <script> tag instead of eval()?

Tags: javascript, jquery

There's some good reasons to avoid the eval() function in JavaScript, namely security risks when including user input in the eval() code. However, in a situation where the eval() code does not include anything affected by user input (in my particular situation, we have dynamic templates defined in XML files - these templates can also specify complex validation functions, javascript code that is embedded in the XML, which is then received by the client via AJAX), is there any reason to avoid the eval() function?

I came up (I'm probably not the first, but I haven't seen this done) with a solution using a dynamically created inline  tag instead of eval():

```
$(scriptObject).text(strJSCode);
```

A simple example can be seen at **http://jsfiddle.net/H7EG9/1/** (I know this example **does** use user input, but that's just to make it easy to demonstrate).

Is there any reason to do this instead of eval()? The outcome is basically the same, although this option might appear less "scary" to the die-hard foes of eval().

Comment: Is there any reason to do `eval()` instead of this?

Comment: 99.9% of the time eval should not be used to do what the person is doing. Why? Because they have no idea how to do it the correct way. And without testing, I am betting it does not work in IE.

Comment: Yes: eval is Evil ! (A good practice is: try to not use them, anyway...)

Comment: Comments such as "eval is evil" and "people don't know who to use it" are unhelpful. Please back up such statements with explanations, proof, and logic.

Comment: The only difference I can think of is that yours would put the `<script>` tag in the DOM, and maybe eat up a little extra memory to store it there, where `eval` wouldn't. At least I think that's true - not 100% sure.

Comment: @epascarello of COURSE it didn't work in IE :/ but I updated it now so it does: http://jsfiddle.net/H7EG9/1/ I'm not sure why I was messing with a data URI anyway.

Answer (score 1):

I would use `eval` instead of creating script tags.

Script tags create overhead (they are DOM elements) but more importantly, you will need to use some sort of global variable to access the script in the script tags. If you use eval, you can simply do

```
var evalFunction = eval("(function(){...})"); // wrap function in () to make it an expression
var result = evalFunction(val);
```

Answer (score 0):

IE8 and below do not allow scripts to be served in `data:` format. In that regard, `eval()` is more reliable.

That being said, if you are using AJAX to download a JS file from which you are getting that string, you could just set `scriptObject.src = 'path/to/script.js';` The browser will have the file in cache and will therefore load it immediately.

Comment: The string is not in a JS file. It is specified in an XML file.

Comment: Maybe it should be? Well, anyway, getting dynamic scripts to run can be a tricky business. It's generally much easier to have static `.js` files on the server, and then have other things point to them.

Comment: It can't be. XML templates are stored in the database and managed through an online portal. The templates specify any special validation. The validation is specified in javascript, as it can be complex. Creating individual JS files for every single template's validation functions would be ridiculous in this situation.

Comment: IE9 does not seem to allow it either. I modified it to use the jQuery text() method instead: http://jsfiddle.net/H7EG9/1/

Answer (score 0):

eval is easy to write, but it is nearly as easy to add a script element to the head or body and append the js text to the new script element. Some edge cases, like variable hoisting, behave a little oddly when evaling a script.